# ¿Por qué no se guardan las imágenes en caché?

Tags: java, android, imagen, picasso

Estoy usando `Picasso` para poder traer imágenes a una aplicación Android desde un servidor `REST`.

El problema es que sí trae las imágenes, pero ***no las está guardando en memoria caché***. Esto es en una Lista personalizada `ListView`.

En dicha lista personalizada, para evitar sobrecargar el servidor, designo a Picasso la tarea de descargar las imágenes para cada ítem que encuentre en la lista. Todo bien con las primeras, pero solo cuando recién deslizo hasta los que no son visibles, recién los carga y las primeras imágenes desaparecen (como si volvieran a cargarse de nuevo).

Aquí os dejo el código:

**ArticuloAdapter.java**

```
package com.movil.tienda.listadapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.movil.tienda.R;
import com.movil.tienda.activity.ArticuloActivity;
import com.movil.tienda.pojo.Articulo;
import com.movil.tienda.util.AppSession;
import com.movil.tienda.util.Methods;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Adapter utilizado para la lista personalizada de artículos.
 * Created by Jose Maria on 01/08/2017.
 */

public class ArticuloAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    protected Activity activity;
    protected List<Articulo> list;
    protected Picasso picasso;

    public ArticuloAdapter(Activity act, List<Articulo> list) {
        this.activity = act;
        this.list = list;
        this.picasso = Picasso.with(act);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return this.list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    /**
     * Por ahora, no se implementa, hasta que se haga una conexión a un servidor.
     * @param i
     * @param view
     * @param viewGroup
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Articulo item = this.list.get(i);
        TextView nombre, precio;
        ImageView foto;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_articulo, null);
        nombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_article_name);
        precio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_article_price);
        foto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_article_img);
        nombre.setText(item.getNombre());
        precio.setText(Methods.parsePrecio(item.getPrecio()));
        Log.i("Imagen de articulo", Methods.Parameters.ARTICULO_GET_IMAGEN + item.getId());
        this.picasso.load(Methods.Parameters.ARTICULO_GET_IMAGEN + item.getId()).into(foto);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.activity, ArticuloActivity.class);
        AppSession.getInstance().setAttribute(Methods.Parameters.SESSION_ARTICULO, this.list.get(i).getId());
        this.activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.list.clear();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Picasso` optimiza de una muy buena forma el cargado de imágenes, crea un cache para evitar peticiones al servidor y descargar nuevamente las imágenes.

Pero este proceso de carga de la imagen de caché nuevamente al `ImageView` puede en ocasiones presentarse como si se estuviera cargando nuevamente la imagen, primeramente porque requiere un proceso de manipulación de los bits que conforman la imagen para agregarlo al `ImageView` y segundo por el proceso de reciclamiento de tus vistas, ya que por buena practica la imágenes no deberían quedarse siempre en el `ListView`, esto ocasionaría problemas de memoria.

Te sugiero habilites la opción `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` para que puedas ver en realidad se esta cargando de caché la imagen:

```
Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Más información:

http://square.github.io/picasso/